# CrmRestKit vs XrmServiceToolkit

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, xrmservicetoolkit

I am looking into different libraries available to assist with javascript development with CRM 2013 (and CRM 2011).

We currently use CrmRestKit, but I am looking into the option of moving over to use the XrmServiceToolkit to make use of some of the additional helper classes available (Notifications being one of them).

Has anybody got and reasons against moving to the XrmServiceToolkit, it would be very useful in helping us with our decision?

**CrmRestKit Specifics**
Acando CRM 5.0 CrmRestKit Version 0.0.1 which is based on 'MSCRM4 Web Service Toolkit for JavaScript v2.1' (http://crmtoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/48329)

**XrmServiceToolkit Details**
V 2.1 (2011 / 2013)
http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have extensively used the XrmServiceToolkit in our projects. We mainly use it to execute FetchXml queries from javascript. Really, it is a great tool, but we have observed one issue, it just ignores the distinct attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XrmServiceToolkit is one of the most used and it's still being updated.

You can check also this project by Jason Lattimer to help you in the transition:

https://crmrestbuilder.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

XrmServiceToolkit is a good library but it bugs with the new CRM 2015 version for the Fetch part.

The fetchxml parsing is based on the node position, and the node position changed with CRM 2015.